# Is there an easy way to generate the boiler-plate code of MuJoCo's XML from a .usd (universal scene description) file?

Tags: 3d, mujoco

At the end, I need to simulate my roller-chain-with-sprockets mechanism (which is itself a part of a bigger, resisted-motion system). Because of the inherent complexity of the mechanism (the unavoidable slack, and the tricky positioning of the links around the sprockets), I had to model it in Fusion 360. Then I exported the models into a single .usdz file. Though I am a beginner in MuJoCo and its python library, I think I can learn enough to hand-code the XML file needed by the MuJoCo's 'Simulate' app to run my setup. But the problem is that there are about 130 roller-chain links in total, and it would take me a ton of time to export and code each and every one of them into the XML. So, can anyone provide me with suggestions of any workarounds for this problem?

[This is a render of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZMxE.jpg)

Feel free to provide your insights or ask for more details. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it's so simple. I realized (rather just recalled) that when I export the fusion 360 model to individual obj files, their positions are preserved. Now I can just write a python script to import each of them into MuJoCo XML. 